# Font does not apply to all label elements

Tags: html, css, forms, markup

When i put a style "font-family: 'Bevan', cursive" to `.label`, it applies only to email label. Help!!
   Got some markup here:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bevan" rel="stylesheet">
<form action="#" name="user-form" class="form">
 <div class="form" id="us_name">
  <label for="user-name" class="label">Ваше имя</label>
   <input name="user-name" placeholder="Type your beautiful name ^_^" value="" required />
</div>
 <div class="form" id="us_mail">
  <label for="user-email" class="label">Email</label>
   <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email goes here ;)" value="" required />
</div>
<div class="form" id="submit">
 <input type="submit" value="Отправить" />
</div>
<div class="form" id="message">
 <textarea name="message" rows="8" cols="40"></textarea>
</div>
 </form>
```

Comment: show us your css please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It did not understand these characters `Ваше имя`.

You need change the `Ваше имя` text by other characters.

Answer (score 1):

Your google font does not support your charset( cyrillic?) change your font

Answer (score 0):

It will be hard to know what is wrong exactly without ur CSS.

I would recommend you to add `!important` after defining you font for `label` and `.label`. However do note that this is a generic fix, try to reduce usage of `!important` as much as possible.

Comment: .form {
 padding: 15px;
 display: flex;
 align-items: flex-start;
 flex-direction: column; 
}

.label {
  font-family: 'Bevan', cursive;
}

textarea {
 resize: none;
}

Answer (score 0):

it is working

```css
label{
   font-family: 'Bevan', cursive; 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bevan" rel="stylesheet">
<form action="#" name="user-form" class="form">
 <div class="form" id="us_name">
  <label for="user-name" class="label">Ваше имя</label>
   <input name="user-name" placeholder="Type your beautiful name ^_^" value="" required />
</div>
 <div class="form" id="us_mail">
  <label for="user-email" class="label">Email</label>
   <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email goes here ;)" value="" required />
</div>
<div class="form" id="submit">
 <input type="submit" value="Отправить" />
</div>
<div class="form" id="message">
 <textarea name="message" rows="8" cols="40"></textarea>
</div>
 </form>
```